# Google Ads displaying on all browsers except Safari. (Adx/AdSense in safari, Ad Server for the rest)

Tags: google-adsense, google-ads, google-tag-manager, google-ad-manager

**Test page** (ads only enabled for certain counties so please let me know yours if you're trying to troubleshoot): http://www.fitsnews.com/category/healthcare/

Two ads on this page (one 728/90 and one 300x600). They are rendering on all browsers except Safari desktop and Safari Mobile. When I use `google_console=1` on Safari, I see `Ad unit did not fill` and no Creative ID or Line ID. When I view the same ad on Chrome, the ad appears and those values are populated.

When I view Delivery Tools in admanager, I see the demand channel as

```
On Safari: AdX/AdSense (and no ads show)
On Chrome: Ad Server (ads are showing)
```

When I click 'Delivery Diagnostics' on Safari and then click 'View non delivery reasons', I see this under the main display:

```
Why the line item wasn't selected
Current simulation
Line item not found. This typically means that the line item is not targeting as expected or is not serving.  Learn more
```

I have checked and there are no browser restrictions. There are no errors in my console. On Safari, I do see the 2 ad calls going out to https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?... but they return minimal data compared to the Chrome network calls to the same URLs

This isn't just my browser. Across the country are 10 of my workmates in different regions - none of which can see the ad display in Safari.

The setup: Wordpress website using Advanced Ads.

Please let me know if there is a better S.E. site to post this on. I wasn't sure..

This question was asked of the google ad manager community to no avail. I am hoping someone here can shed some light, or at least give me some clues on what to look into.

Answer (score 1):

The problem turns out to be the geotargeting. Apple's IP anonymization apparently makes it so the user's geolocation is not reported to GAM and since we're targeting certain locales, it's not showing. When I remove our geotargeting filter, the ads show in Safari.

Frustrating that there was no real way to troubleshoot this. Not much documentation that I could find either.

https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/13389269?sjid=5748345362852066035-NA&authuser=5