# Are there workarounds re: geo-targeting with Google Ad Manager and Safari (b/c Apple IP anonymization)?

Tags: google-adsense, google-ad-manager

We just [ran into an issue](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/142268/google-ads-displaying-on-all-browsers-except-safari-adx-adsense-in-safari-ad/142407#142407) where our ads were getting blocked by Safari due to geo-targeting certain areas. Our ads are mostly local and we are trying to serve them to the right audience, not to mention that the businesses are paying for impressions in certain geotargeted areas.

[Apple's IP anonymization](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/13389269?sjid=5748345362852066035-NA&authuser=5) has been in effect for a couple of years, and in our case that means we can't use any goetargeting. Even setting it to be the united states didn't work. We can only see the ads in Safari when we remove all geography filters in GAM. I can't be the first person considering how to approach this problem, yet I am unable to find any substantive articles about it on the internet.

One idea I had was if we could send geo-relevant data with the ad request. Then we could omit it for Safari but capture it for other browsers. Something like

```
googletag.defineSlot( ... ).addService(googletag.pubads())
.setTargeting( 'geography', 'Cary, North Carolina, US, Raleigh, North Carolina, US, Fort Myers, Florida, US' ).
```

I could not find documentation on this approach. Does anyone else do something like this?

Is there any advice on how to reconcile this issue? Is the answer truly to just not use geotargeting at all in GAM or to forsake all iphones and mac users?